# Jquery - порядок вставки элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему `</details>` вставляется раньше чем `user`?

```
function renderGroup(group) {
                var body = $("body");
                body.append("<details open='open'><summary>" + group.name + "</summary>");
                for (var i = 0; i < group.users.length; i++){
                    body.append("user");
                }
                body.append("</details>");
            }
```

На выходе:

```
<body>
<details open="">
<summary>1</summary>
</details>
useruser
<details>
<summary>2</summary>
</details>
useruser
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что когда вы пишете `body.append("<details open='open'><summary>" + group.name + "</summary>");` браузер автоматически добавляет закрывающий тег. 
Для того чтобы этого избежать лучше делать так:

```js
function renderGroup(group) {
    var body = $('body');
    var details = '<details open="open"><summary>' + group.name + '</summary>';
    for (var i = 0; i < group.users.length; i++){
        details += group.users[i];
    }
    details += '</details>';
    body.append(details);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение